# In Laravel with ReCaptcha V3, how do I access the "score" returned from a rule?

Tags: laravel, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

In *Laravel*, I am setting up *Google ReCaptcha V3* which now returns a "score".  I've managed to setup a validation rule to allow my form to submit (all working), but this is only returning true or false to pass the validation.

How do I base this on the score instead?

I'm using this composer package to help me out - https://github.com/google/recaptcha

This is in my controller (where I am sending the token to validate with the server):

```
// validation
$this->validate( $request, array(
    'g_recaptcha_response' => ['required', 'string', new Captcha()]
));
```

This is the rule:

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha;

class Captcha implements Rule
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $recaptcha = new ReCaptcha('SECRET');
        $response = $recaptcha->verify($value, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        return $response->isSuccess();
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'Are you a robot?';
    }

}
```

Can I access the class somehow from the controller?  I can see in the package that I need to use `->getScore()` but I don't know how to access it?

Comment: I am curious to know why do you need the captcha value in controller? I believe the `new Captcha()` will help you validate it captcha is correct. Then  you can proceed with the controller logic considering the captcha was entered correctly.

Comment: I would like to see and retrieve the score that's provided.  But I don't know how to view this score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are doing in the validation rule, you can also get the score in controller :

```
public function something(YourRequest $request){

    $recaptcha = new ReCaptcha('SECRET');
    $response = $recaptcha->verify($request->g_recaptcha_response, $request->ip());
    $score =  $response->getScore();
}
```

More available methods of response can be found [here](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/master/src/ReCaptcha/Response.php)